# Qual a diferença entre puts() e fputs()?

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Sei que ambas as funções são para exibir *strings* na tela. Mas qual a diferença entre elas? Qual delas é melhor de usar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não é uma questão de ser melhor, é uma questão de onde você precisa que seja feita a escrita. [`puts()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) escreve no console, enquanto que [`fputs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) escreve através de um manipulador em arquivo aberto anteriormente. veja as declarações da funções que deixam clara a diferença.

```
int puts(const char *s);

int fputs(const char *s, FILE *stream);
```

Embora não seja comum, é claro que o a `fputs()` pode ser usada para escrever em console também, se o *stream* para o arquivo seja o próprio console que para o sistema operacional não deixa de ser um arquivo.

Um exemplo simplificado usando ambos:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char s[100];
    fp = fopen("datafile.txt", "w");
    while(fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != NULL) { //o fgets está lendo do console (stdin)
        fputs(s, fp);  // escreve no arquivo
        puts(s); //escreve no console
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/Fputs.c).

Costuma-se usar [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) e `fprintf()` no lugar destas funções, já que elas são mais poderosas em formatação do s dados. Mas se não precisa da formatação, algo mais simples deve ser usado.

Comment: Atenção a uma diferença entre as duas funções: `fputs()` escreve exactamente o que se manda; `puts()` acrescenta um `'\n'`.