# puts() e printf(), quando e qual usar?

Tags: c, console, printf

As solicitações de entrada da dados geralmente são precedidas de um texto indicativo do que desejasse receber e geralmente não possuem dados para serem formatados.

Se não estão sendo apresentado dados de variáveis no texto de solicitação, porquê nos livros e os professores sempre usam o `printf()`? A função `puts()` não serve para apresentar 'texto' simples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As duas funções são iguais, porém a função `puts()` adiciona uma quebra de linha, igual a `printf("\n")`

Porem ao usar o `puts()` temos de ter noção que apenas imprime a string, não temos o controlo do `printf()` em que podemos imprimir algo como `printf("int: %d, float: %f", x, y)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Nesse exemplo do *Hello world* o compilador converte o `printf()` para `puts()`

```
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
mov edi,str.Helloworld!
call dword imp.puts
mov eax,0x0
pop rbp
ret
```

Para concluir, o `printf()` é um pouco mais lento porque é preciso formatar as variaveis e concatenar para uma string para ser imprimido. Porém essa diferença é praticamente irrelevante.

Comment: Esclarecedor, já que estou apenas começando já vou assumir isso como prática, quando quiser apenas escrever textos como "Hello word!" irei utilizar o `puts()`, assim o compilador tem menos uma tarefa, e ganho um pouco mais em performance...msm que a diferença seja praticamente irrelevante...de grão, em grão... kkk.

Comment: @J.Ferreira em geral os programadores experientes não fazem isto, hoje em dia há zero motivos para usar o `puts()`.

Comment: Essas coisas que eu não entendo, se o comando tem suas vantagens ou ao menos não tem desvantagens e no final o compilador o utiliza tbém, pq a comunidade não o utiliza? há em algum lugar em que essas boas práticas são citadas?(Perguntas retóricas que aceitariam respostas)

Comment: o `puts()` tem muitas limitações, é por isso que não usado, até porque o desempenho é igual ao `printf()` aquela diferença que o compilador faz é insignificante

Answer (score 6):

A diferença básica é que o [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) possui formatação e tem um controle mais amplo de como imprimir os dados desejados, é uma solução completa de impressão. O [`puts()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/puts) é uma solução bem simples para jogar caracteres no console, você tem que entregar exatamente o que deseja, ele não manipula nada, então não pode mandar um número ou um conteúdo com um texto e esperar que saia algo visível como o esperado por um humano. A única coisa que ele faz a mais que o `printf()` é colocar uma quebra de linha automaticamente.

Já respondi mais sobre ele em [Qual a diferença entre puts() e fputs()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32329/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).